# Issue in setting up Microsoft Bing speech recognition

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api, bing-speech

I am trying to use Microsoft's Bing Speech Recognition service library. The following command has to be given in the cmd with arguments. But I have no idea in which format I should enter this command. I could not find it anywhere. Can someone help me? Should I specify an existing audio WAV file? Should the path be given? What is "audio locale"?

> Run `SpeechClientSample.exe` with the following arguments:
>
> - `Arg[0]`: Specify an input audio WAV file.
> - `Arg[1]`: Specify the audio locale.
> - `Arg[2]`: Specify the recognition modes: *Short* for the `ShortPhrase` mode and *Long* for the `LongDictation` mode.
> - `Arg[3]`: Specify the subscription key to access the speech recognition service.

See [Get started with the speech recognition service library in C# for .NET Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedcsharpservicelibrary).

Comment: _audio locale_ is the language of the audio file, like "en-us" for american english or "fr-fr" for french.

Answer (score 0):

if you run it from Visual Studio, open the properties of the SpeechClientSample project and on the Debug tab - you can add the command line arguments in there.  Here's a sample:  batman.wav en-US long 1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a.  You don't need any quotes or anything - just a space between each argument.